# Clear padding between <li> tags

Tags: html, css

I actually have a menu with 3 links and 1 search bar.

The code looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="search" id="search"/><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically I have given a style to the .menu class which's padding is a bit much for the textbox I'm using as the last item.

Is there anything with I could clear the Padding of the -.menu class and give a new one or even a margin, to position my textbox correctly?

Or I should just create the textbox NOT in the `<li>` ???

Edit: This is the css I'm using:

```
.menu{
padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Please also post your CSS. Why do you have the empty anchor tag after the input?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter, I have just edited. The link isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target that particular input inside the .menu, you could target `.menu li input`, like this:

```
.menu{
padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
display: inline;
}

.menu li input{
padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
display: inline;
}
```

You can change the attributes (such as padding/margins) inside `.menu li input` to whatever suits you without affecting the other elements.

**jsFiddle here** - http://jsfiddle.net/st5ZA/1/.

Comment: My menu items are inline. The last item is the Search box. The problem is that when I insert that search box in the li tag, everything gets messed up. Because the textbox's padding will be the same as the container menu's. So I want to clear that margin of the textbox's li tag and rewrite it.

Comment: @user1406071 Have you seen my jsFiddle? you change change the margin/padding to whatever you like in each of the two CSS classes I gave. I don't understand what exactly is 'messed up' as it doesn't look very messed up to me - can you show me a picture of exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="search" id="search"/><a href=""></a></li>
```

CSS

```
.menu li input{
padding: 2em;
margin: 2em;
}
```